# RPM: update files externally and "fake" rpm-upgrade

Tags: rpm

First, yes, that may be nasty stuff and breaks all rules handling with rpm-packaging...I know... but I've got following situation to resolve:

Our application has the ability to remotely update files by a mechanism where only the files that have changed are transmitted via network. The ability to transfer only needed files and not the whole package is needed due to bandwith limitations and further because hundreds of installations may get updated. The amount of transmitted data is quite relevant and should be as minimal as possible.

Now, we'd like to roll out RPM packages. There is one package that holds the "Base" installation with the update-service. And one package with everything else, that should be updated by the update-service. Let's call it "Runtime".
Further there is the need to be able to make normal upgrades via the commandline tools ("rpm -U" etc.)

So we have two Packages:

- Base Package (which is able to upgrade the "Runtime" Package)
- Runtime Package (which can be upgraded by the update-service and by command-line)

Further the upgrade can happen via:

- Upgrade-Service (part of the Base-Package)
- rpm -U

The solution I was forcing was to create two versions of the Runtime package. One for the service and one for the "normal" rpm:

The service-rpm doesn't inlcude files at all - they are copied by the service. This RPM is needed only to keep track of the version in the package-management and is installed by the upgrade-service.

The other "normal" RPM has a zip with all files in it that are extracted by a post-install script.

The reason for this is, that if I just include all files in the "normal" RPM, the package-management tracks them and will delete all files when upgrading with the "Upgrade-Version"-RPM since they are not included anymore.

Actually, doing the "zipping-trick" seems really ugly and I was wondering if there is another possibility to either

- prevent the upgrade deleting the updated files
- or hack into the package management to tell the right version
- and probably track the remotely updated files as well

Any ideas for solving this (or achieving one of my solutions)?

Comment: You can use the `%ghost` file modifier when building a package to tell rpm that the file exists and is part of your package but will not actually be *in* the package itself. That should prevent it from removing the files on upgrade.

Comment: RPM is the wrong tool for your job it sounds like (indicated by your subversion of most of its facilities), but I would check out creating a repo and using delta RPMs for the upgrade.